# How can I execute an arbitrary string in Python or C++?

Tags: python, c++

A trivial way to build a calculator would be one in which one didn't need to parse the input string themselves --- i.e., if one could rely on the language's built-in calculator to do it.

In order to accomplish this one would expect the existence of some sort of "function" `F(std::string X)` which takes in a string such as `"7 + 3"` and removes its quotes. That would allow one to do this: `int k = F("7 + 3") = 7 + 3`.

Beyond a calculator, what if I wanted to enter a statement? Say I want to reserve a line `F(argv[1]);` in my program where one can enter something like "`std::cout << 'Hello, World!'`" or "`break`" or "`case 17817:`" and so on. In C++ we can assign values to a variable from the command line: so why can't I set up a placeholder, not for a number, character or string, but an entire statement?

If my supposition is correct, I am delusional to expect something like this to exist. Although it is clear to see that a myriad of issues would come into existence with the existence of such feature, I still wonder what difficulties would exist in implementing something that merely removes the quotes around a string.

Question: Does such "function" F exist in C++ or Python be it for simple expressions or even full-fledged statements?

Comment: Which would be the return type of `F(std::string)`? (Remember that it cannot depend of value inside the string).

Comment: No [python `eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Such a function exists in Python. It's the [`eval` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) that interprets an arbitrary string. For example, you could try the following in a Python interpreter:

```py
>>> def calc(e):
...     return eval(e)
...
>>> calc("2+3")
5
```

The `eval` function can take arbitrary valid Python statements. So as you might guess, in general `eval` is **unsafe** to use since it can be exploited by an attacker.

Most interpreted languages, such as JavaScript, Ruby etc., do provide such dynamic-evaluation functions. However, this isn't possible within compiled languages, like C++. One cannot simply "interpret" a string during runtime -- the compiler must be invoked to parse, compile and generate executable code first.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, sorry. Also, just to be clear, it's not that C++ _can't_ do it -- after all C++ is Turing complete :) It's just that the "run-time environment" for compiled languages does not include the parsing and code-generation logic for dynamic evaluation to be possible.